# Fixing "Word found unreadable content in corrupt..." programmatically

Tags: .net, ms-word, openxml, office-interop

I'm getting a OpenXml generated docx file from another system. When try using open the file in my application using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application.Open(filename)` I get a `The file appears to be corrupted` exception.

When I manually open the docx file I'm greeted with a `Word found unreadable content in corrupt xxx.docx. Do you want to recover the contents of this document? If you trust the source of this document, click Yes.` prompt. When I click `Yes`, it is able to recover the document in a new unsaved Word file.

I have tried comparing the previous corrupt.docx file's document.xml with the recovered.docx file's document.xml. While there are many of formatting changes between the two document.xmls (extra space between closing xml-tags), the main difference was the AltChunk actually was embedded into the recovered.docx and there were several empty "run" tags that got removed. I'm not sure what would be causing the file to be considered corrupt as those don't seem like they should.

That said, is there a way to run whatever process happens when I click `Yes` to that `...Do you want to recover the contents of this document?...` prompt programatically through my application; this would be the ideal? Less preferably, is there a way to tell what parts of the xml is actually corrupting in a word doc?

Comment: Keep an original file, then open another copy and repair it. Then open both in the Open XML SDK Productivity tool (part of the Open XMK SDK), and click on Compare Files. Click on the View Package Code tab to see what code would make the difference between the two files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That said, is there a way to run whatever process happens when I click
>   Yes to that ...Do you want to recover the contents of this
>   document?... prompt programnatically through my application; this would
>   be the ideal? Less preferably, is there a way to tell what parts of
>   the xml is actually corrupting in a word doc?

1. No, that's not exposed to the outside
2. Theoretically, validation could be possible. But given there's an AltChunk involved, that might not turn up the problem. The content of AltChunk isn't integrated until Word processes the document, at which time it's integrated. And if what's coming in "breaks" something, the validation won't pick that up.

In this particular case, I might try removing the AltChunk manually (the pieces are in a few places in the zip file) and see if the file can open without it. But if you're not intimately familiar with the Word Open XML zip package it might be better to ask the producer/source of the document.

Comment: @mche Without seeing/analyzing the Word Open XML, etc. it's not possible to offer an opinion. It's not known, for example, whether the altChunk and the image interact.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have tried removing the AltChunk (by process of: renaming file extension to zip -> extracting -> editing -> zipping). The AltChunk was wrapped around a tablerow and tablecol so removing those allowed things to open smoothly. So it does appear to be related to the AltChunk process. 

I did try removing the img tag that contained the base64 image and that allowed the document to open without issue. So it seems to be some sort of issue with how word processes the image?

Comment: sorry accidentally deleted my other comment as I was trying to edit and some text got fumbled up.

Could you elaborate what you mean when you say "It's not known, for example, whether the altChunk and the image interact."?

@cindy

Comment: No one but you has seen the actual Word Open XML. Without that information it's impossible to even make a guess as to what the problme might be. In any case, any such considerations would belong in a new question, not this one.